# Assigning Key Value Pairs in R

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I am confused on how I can assign a key-value pair using a list in R.

I have a data frame which has multiple rows and multiple columns. I have an ID column and another column called price,

I want to create a for loop that loops through my ID column and creates a list using the elements of the ID column as the *key* and elements of the price column as the *value*

```
id <- seq(1,10,1)
price <- abs(rnorm(10))
x1 <- seq(100,1000,100)

data <- data.frame(x1, price, id)

for (i in data$id){
  for (y in data$price){
    value = y
}
key = i
  alist = list()
  alist[[key]] = value  
}
```

This returns a list of length 1 with the entry `10`

Obviously my R programming concepts are wrong and hence it isn't working. So if someone could clarify what I am doing wrong that would be great! The data is trivial and my actual data is basically the same just a lot more columns, I however want to focus on only these two columns.

As a side note, for loops get extremely slow if you have many rows, so if someone knows how to do this in a more efficient manner please do enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: The problem in your code is that you replace `alist` at each iteration of the outer loop with an empty list. You need to initialize this list outside both loops. Also, `alist <- split(price, id)` will  give you the result directly.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification! I need to go back and understand how loops work. Also I'll try the split() function too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option using `tibble::deframe()`.

```
library(tibble)

as.list(deframe(data[c('id', 'price')]))
  
# $`1`
# [1] 0.16755
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 0.7488444
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 0.5633155
# 
# $`4`
# [1] 0.5785397
# 
# $`5`
# [1] 2.016018
# 
# $`6`
# [1] 0.4830829
# 
# $`7`
# [1] 0.8575976
# 
# $`8`
# [1] 0.8113425
# 
# $`9`
# [1] 0.4937693
# 
# $`10`
# [1] 1.044266
```

Comment: This method works the best for me of all the ones I tried, thank you for letting me know about the deframe function too!

Answer (score 1):

In R no need for loops in many cases.
Should it be?

```
> set.seed(42)
> 
> id <- seq(1,10,1)
> price <- abs(rnorm(10))
> x1 <- seq(100,1000,100)
> data <- data.frame(x1, price, id)
> 
> setNames(as.list(data$price),data$id)
$`1`
[1] 1.370958

$`2`
[1] 0.5646982

$`3`
[1] 0.3631284

$`4`
[1] 0.6328626

$`5`
[1] 0.4042683

$`6`
[1] 0.1061245

$`7`
[1] 1.511522

$`8`
[1] 0.09465904

$`9`
[1] 2.018424

$`10`
[1] 0.0627141
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to loop, and you probably don't need to, you only need one loop.

```
alist = list()

for (i in data$id){
  key = i
  
  alist[[key]] = data[[key, 'price']]
}

alist
```

```
Sample Output

[[1]]
[1] 0.6174008

[[2]]
[1] 1.354075

[[3]]
[1] 1.17742

[[4]]
[1] 0.8964335

[[5]]
[1] 1.577932

[[6]]
[1] 1.29356

[[7]]
[1] 0.7557945

[[8]]
[1] 0.7060919

[[9]]
[1] 0.1324002

[[10]]
[1] 1.022202
```